# GUI build error about "undefined reference"

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, language, build

I followed github's build guide on my ubuntu 14.04 mate x64

Everything looks fine in installing dependencies.

No file was modified. Just clone and build.

But when I run the build command ./build.sh

It showed this error.

`` /tmp/ccOA8dOf.ltrans23.ltrans.o: In function `tools::log_stack_trace(char const*)':
<artificial>:(.text+0x4fc): undefined reference to `_Ux86_64_getcontext'
<artificial>:(.text+0x51c): undefined reference to `_ULx86_64_init_local'
<artificial>:(.text+0x569): undefined reference to `_ULx86_64_get_proc_name'
<artificial>:(.text+0x735): undefined reference to `_ULx86_64_step'
<artificial>:(.text+0x755): undefined reference to `_ULx86_64_get_reg'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:258: recipe for target 'release/bin/monero-wallet-gui' failed
make: *** [release/bin/monero-wallet-gui] Error 1
~/monero-core ``

Moreover, I would like to test a new translation file later.

I found there was a post said just update languages.xml. Is that all I need to update?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is libunwind. It probably was wrongly detected. In the meantime, you should be able to build by removing libunwind-dev (or similar) from your system.

It might also be that you changed your system and cmake kept some cache. A rebuild from scratch (that is, removing all build trees) might fix this, if this is indeed the case.

Comment: Thanks! Very useful hint.
I removed libunwind-dev and clone the git again. And the build works!
But when I launch the app, showed qml-module-qt-labs-folderlistmodelis not installed. So I install it, then the GUI launched perfectly now!